# PHP Link user table to another table

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, user-registration

Hi I am in the process of making a website that includes a user registration system for my final year of high school major project. The website stores driving logs for learner drivers. I'm kind of confused as to how I should desgin the database. I have a users table which stores the personal information of each user of the site. However, I would like the user to be able to insert information into another table which would be their "logbook" and this to be displayed on the my account page. Do I need to create a table within the database for each user or is there a way of connecting the tables so that i do not have to.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create a table for each user. Instead, add a column in your "logbook" table which will contain and refer to the "id" of the user it's tracking. This will likely be the primary key of your "users" table. Then, to get the logs for a specific user, you would query the logbook table for rows only with at specific user ID.

Furthermore, in a more sophisticated setup, you can add constraints to link the two columns. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

U will not need table for each user...
Just one table will help u out...
The other table where u want to store user logs should only have reference to user I'd that u have created in users table..
Primary and foreign key - relational table  concepts

For eg:
Let ur user has 
1.userid
2.first name
3.lastname.... And other colums

Then ur userlogbook wala table should have
1.logid
2.userid
3.other columns...

Hope u got it..

Answer (score 0):

You only need **1** table for the users, each user will be a row inside that table.

---

As you see in this table below, you need a way to be able to track which logbook record belongs to which user. That's done by storing the users ID (or any **unique** identifier, **usually the primary key**) to know exactly which user created the record.

```
--------------                 -----------------
| User Table |                 | Logbook Table |
-------------------------      -----------------------------------
| id | name | ...etc... |      | id | user_id | date | ...etc... |
-------------------------      -----------------------------------
  |                                     |
  |_____________________________________|
```

I don't know how your system works, but I assume you know when a user is logged in right? Probably store their `id` in a session yeah? Well when you're inserting the logbook record, all you need to do is parse through their user ID in addition:

```
INSERT INTO logbook (id, user_id, .....) VALUES (NULL, $THE_USER_ID_FROM_SESSION, .....)
```

<sup>*The above is pseudo code, you'd need to sanitize the input and actually assign the user id to a variable.*</sup>

Now for fetching the user-specific information, all you need to do is add a simple `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT id,column_1,column_2,... FROM logbook WHERE `user_id` = $THE_USER_ID_FROM_SESSION
```

<sup>*The above is pseudo code, you'd need to sanitize the input and actually assign the user id to a variable.*</sup>

---

There are a few questions I have, how much reading/writing are you going to be doing to the table? How are your tables set up?